# Satellite Card Windows Driver: The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, satellite

I have formatted my computer using WINDOWS 7, I have installed all drivers however I keep getting this error: `The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)`. I tried with many drivers finders but no result!

Comment: What make and model laptop? I suspect its a Toshiba, but the specifying both would probably be helpful. Also see [SD Driver doesn't work](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/General-Troubleshooting/SD-Driver-doesn-t-work/td-p/282767) on Toshiba forums. It looks like you need ["Texas Instruments Flash Media Driver"](http://www.google.com/search?q=toshiba+"Texas+Instruments+Flash+Media+Driver").

Comment: It is actually a desktop, HP xw8400 WorkStation.